# Wifi is frequently disconnecting on Lenovo X1 Carbon 7G and X1 Yoga 4G

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, lenovo-vantage

My wifi gets disconnected every 5 to 10 minutes with a brand new computer. I already updated and reinstalled drivers. Though my other computer's connection is stable, I don't think it is a router issue. No errors are detectable. Under driver, there is no Power tab available. Using windows build Version 10.0.19041 Build 19041, Windows 10 Pro.

A wifi report says: InfrastructureFailure Reason:The driver disconnected while associating

> Interface:Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHzInterface GUID: c23452ff-20b8-4c5c-9dd4-af65ca6408afConnection Mode:Automatic connection with a profileProfile:SHAW-5AC800SSID:SHAW-5AC800BSS Type:InfrastructureSession Duration: 0 hours 0 minutes 1 secondsDisconnect Reason:The driver disconnected while associating.EventId Time Message8000 2020-06-13T17:53:38 [+]WLAN AutoConfig service started a connection to a wireless network.Network Adapter: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHzInterface GUID: {c23452ff-20b8-4c5c-9dd4-af65ca6408af}Connection Mode: Automatic connection with a profileProfile Name: SHAW-5AC800SSID: SHAW-5AC800BSS Type: Infrastructure11000 2020-06-13T17:53:38 [+]Wireless network association started.Network Adapter: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHzInterface GUID: {c23452ff-20b8-4c5c-9dd4-af65ca6408af}Local MAC Address: C8:58:C0:DE:B6:56Network SSID: SHAW-5AC800BSS Type: InfrastructureAuthentication: WPA-PersonalEncryption: AES-CCMP802.1X Enabled: No8002 2020-06-13T17:53:39 [+]WLAN AutoConfig service failed to connect to a wireless network.Network Adapter: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHzInterface GUID: {c23452ff-20b8-4c5c-9dd4-af65ca6408af}Connection Mode: Automatic connection with a profileProfile Name: SHAW-5AC800SSID: SHAW-5AC800BSS Type: InfrastructureFailure Reason:The driver disconnected while associating.RSSI: 2551015 2020-06-13T17:53:39 [+]Interface Token Applied

Comment: You may like to edit your question with some more details like, Operating System, Its version, model of router, firmware of router, if using stock or custom firmware. Wifi Adapter, type of security/encryption/frequency band Wifi is operating. Boot thru some Live Linux or some Live rescue cd/dvd/usb etc and if it can detect WiFi adapter check if the connection is stable or not. If in case you have an external USB WiFi adapter, try plugging that to you computer and check if stable. Try setting channel manually in router. If Windows OS ensure it’s updated.

Comment: The operating system is windows 10. The router is fine. I have no issues with 10 other devices.

Comment: This has been resolved over time. No clue what changed. Manual updates and driver installation did not fix it.